# Question on mass flow and Betz's law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, flow

On Wikipedia I was reading an article on [Betz's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betz%27s_law), where has a statement that lost me:

So the density times the area and speed should be equal in each of the three regions, before, while going through the turbine and afterwards.

The force exerted on the wind by the rotor is the mass of air multiplied by its acceleration. In terms of the density, surface area and velocities, this can be written:

$$F=ma = m \frac{dv}{dt}=\dot{m}\Delta v .$$

It would be nice to get an explanation, how to jump from second law to the last equality, meaning:

$$m \frac{dv}{dt}=\dot{m}\Delta v.$$

Could someone help me understanding this? Please I may have been lost for the mathematical or physical formality.

Answer (score 1):

How about just this?

$$
F = \Delta m\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t} = \frac{\Delta m}{\Delta t}\Delta v = \dot{m}\Delta v
$$

Comment: I would like to thank you for your point of view, although I am still confused in your equations how you jump from m to $\Delta m (conceptually). Are you allowed to do so? I thought about the product rule would require you to do an addition of F=d/dt(mv)=v dm/dt+ m dv/dt, so deltas would have to obey the same principle, would they not?

Comment: @HeberSarmiento Imagine you are dealing with a small volume element (the whole construction is predicated on that assumption), so instead of using $m$ use $\Delta m$

Answer (score 1):

In this model, it is assumed that the force acting on the turbine of mass $m$ that is equal to $mdv/dt$  is balanced by the loss of impulse flow in unit time which is equal to $\Delta v_adm_a/dt=\rho v_aS(v_1-v_2)$. This is usually puzzling as the turbine rotates rather than accelerating.

Comment: This sure makes more sense, but do you mind showing the loss of impulse ($F \Delta t = \Delta p = \Delta (mv)$) leading to the last equation you have presented (i.e. $mdv/dt= \Delta v_{a} dm_{a}/dt$)? I even tried to use product rule of differentials on the momentum equation d/dt(pv) or came across and considered caverac's answer as a viable one, until reading your post which conceptually makes sense. Although mathematically I am still trying to wrap my head around it, it would be helpful to see you going through these details so I could understand clearly.

Comment: It is assumed that $dm/dt = const$. Consequently, the loss of momentum is due to a decrease in air velocity behind the turbine.

Comment: Thank you for laying out the concepts. It really got me thinking! Now the $\frac{dm} {dt}= constant $, still does not explain how you arrived at $m_{air}\frac{dv}{dt}=\Delta v_{air}\frac{dm_{air}} {dt}$. I am focusing on the  forces in the air element, based on the statement: The force exerted on the wind by the rotor is the mass of air multiplied by its acceleration (action-reaction).

Comment: It is not necessary to prove.This is an obvious fact in aerodynamics that the loss of impulse flow in unit time is equal to $\rho S v_a(v_1-v_2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Due to force exerted by the turbine, wind leaving the turbine has different momentum than when it came in. If you consider a [control volume](http://www.mecheng.iisc.ernet.in/~gtom/me201/ME201Lecs/2017/lecture4.pdf) surrounding the turbine, then in steady state the force exerted on the wind inside the control volume equals the net flux of momentum out of the control volume (by virtue of Reynolds transport theorem). $\dot{m}v_{out}-\dot{m}v_{in}=\dot{m}\Delta v$ is exactly the net momentum flux out of the control volume surrounding the turbine.